# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user error when using Connection string

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-config

When I use a connection string like this in the deployment server for a website, I cannot connect to the database! But the same code, if I run in the same server to test connection string, it connects to the database. What is it I am doing wrong in the connection string? How can the same code connects when debugging and not connecting when live. The error I get on the live website is

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user

Can someone help me? If you need to know anything more, please let me know! Thank you in advance!! This is the web application in VS 2008 and SQL Server 2008.

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Data Source=198.57.59.70;Initial Catalog=Tracking;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `windows` user you're using with your app has valid credentials to access that `ip` you are specifying?

Comment: @EmmanuelRC How do i check that? Are there any settings for SQL  to grant access to websites?